# Merge Stack Overflow accounts with different OpenIDs but same e-mail address

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-accounts, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I already have a Stack Overflow account using another OpenID. When I registered, it was detected automatically (thanks to Mozilla Weave), so I didn't get to choose my "real" OpenID.

How can I recover my other account, or merge this new one with the old one? Both use the same e-mail address.

Answer (score 4):

Email the "contact us" link at the bottom of this page and they'll take care of you.

Comment: I have no idea why you would make this community wiki

Comment: @TheTXI: We should create a new term for random wiki use.

Comment: I accidentally the wiki.

Comment: @TheTXI Is it bad to randomly make a post CW, apart from the lost rep?